# AWS S3, CloudFront and SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https

I have tried setting up a static hosting solution for our web platform by using AWS S3 and CloudFront. It is required to use https, and it needs to be accessed via a custom subdomain.

This is my S3 bucket:
[image]

These are the settings for the CloudFront:
[image]
[image]

The certificate settings look ok to me:
[image]

And finally my DNS record is like this:
`CNAME: "static" -> "d1fd407fp9coo4.cloudfront.net."`

edit: using my default domain provider for DNS, not Route 53.

The aim is to have the resource available at static.dmaglobal.com/logo-frontpage.png via https. It loads fine without (http://static.dmaglobal.com/logo-frontpage.png), but the https-version (https://static.dmaglobal.com/logo-frontpage.png) gives an SSL-error stating the current certificate is for *.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com instead of *.dmaglobal.com. I do not understand where this mismatch comes from, as it seems like the current certificate is correctly set up for our custom domain.

Anyone able to give some pointers on how to proceed from here with this issue?

Comment: How long has it been since you created the CloudFront distribution? I created one with an identical setup a few weeks ago and it kept redirecting to S3 instead of serving the files via CloudFront (thus serving the S3 SSL certificate instead of the one you have configured on CloudFront). Apparently this is a known issue with new CloudFront distributions and you need to wait a few hours for it to start serving files from S3 correctly. Mine started working as expected after a few hours.

Comment: Is was created maybe 2 hours ago, it took a while until it was ready - it spent maybe an hour or so with the state "In Progress" before it changed to "Ready"

Comment: Yeah I had the same experience. I would wait a few more hours for it to start serving files instead of redirecting to S3. Here's the AWS forum post that I went by when I was having the same issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=677452 If it doesn't clear up in a few hours you might want to open a ticket with AWS support.

Comment: Also i just noticed that https://dnschecker.org/#CNAME/static.dmaglobal.com is still resolved directly to the S3 bucket URL instead of the CloudFront. I started by adding the domain directly to the S3 bucket, and only changed it shortly after when I realised I needed to use CloudFront to access via https. So maybe I just have to wait until that change has propagated completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: In the end, it was the proper CNAME value that had not propagated properly yet (as it was initially pointing to S3 before I was aware that CloudFront was required for SSL). As soon as it was, the settings in the OP worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed your DNS record resolves to S3 still.

Instead of CNAME you should create an ALIAS record to Cloudfront distribution. In static record pick A type record, check Yes for Alias and pick the Cloudfront distribution on the dropdown.

The reason for this: ALIAS records are free of charge and they resolve faster.

Comment: The OP didn't say he is using Route53 for DNS. A CNAME record should work fine. It may take longer to propagate a change based on the TTL, but that's it. Not sure why you make the statement that Alias records are free of charge. You pay for a hosted zone in Route53. You do not pay anything extra for any records in that hosted zone, no matter what record type they are.

Comment: @MarkB *queries* against Route 53 Alias records are free when the Alias points to a service target (S3, CloudFront, ELB), otherwise they are billable.

Comment: Just for clarity, I am not using Route 53 in this case. I will post an update on this question once the proper CNAME value has been propagated

Comment: Yes, in case of Route53 & Alias you only pay 0.5$ for hosted zone but for other type of records you pay per query, which can be a high cost if you receive millions of traffic. I ignored the fact that some clients might still use on-premise DNS solutions.